# When the concept of "Ultraviolet completion" of a low energy effective theory first arose?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-field-theory

In modern view any quantum field theory that has any reason (mathematical or physical) to not be tenable at some short length scale is assumed to be replaced by a more fundamental theory, that we call "UV completion".
Such name is given because it completes the previous theory at some higher energy (UV is an abuse of nomenclature to say higher energy than the relevant scale for which I had formulated the first theory).

My understanding is that this is a modern concept (few decades old). For instance I cannot find any trace of such need to complete the model of Fermi contact interactions ( those responsible for muon decay and all $\beta$ decays) even in Enrico Fermi's own speech about the possibility to build a [particle collider around the globe](https://www.fnal.gov/pub/today/archive/archive_2007/today07-02-16.html) (Also in `"Fermi Remembered"  by  James W. Cronin (Editor) - Chapter 9 - What can we learn from high energy accelerators?` ). He gave this speech in 1954 and thought about a fixed target collider (beam on target) which could reach center of mass energy in the TeV range.

In modern view the theory of Fermi interactions has a limited energy range of applicability, because it stops making sense from a mathematical point of view, giving probabilities larger than one if one sticks to perturbation theory. Very importantly, the maximum range of applicability is predictable from perturbation theory itself in the same way the Taylor series of any function can be anticipated to break down if we use it too far away from the point around which it has been expanded. Armed with this knowledge, at the master degree level you already know that, carrying out experiments in the TeV energy range, the "globatron" collider Fermi was discussing would have been the perfect machine to discover the UV completion of Fermi theory of weak interactions. Despite this, Fermi does not make any mention of that in this speech.

Therefore I have a number of questions, among which:

- in the 1950s was there a sense of how Fermi theory of weak interactions should have become untenable at higher energies?
- at what point in time it became clear that quantum field theories can be "effective low energy" theories (and there is no harm in that)

Thanks for your inputs